# Копирование строк в JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Столкнулся со странной ситуацией, есть функция которая должна просто удалить все пробелы в строке:

```
private removeFormat(value: string): string {
  const result = value.split(' ').join('');
  debugger
  return result
}
```

Все вроде придельно просто, но случилось вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу воспроизвести это нигде кроме моего контекста, но у меня воспроизводится стабильно.

Как такое вообще возможно `instanceof value` отвечает что `string`, `value.replace(/ /g, '')` дает такой же результат.

К великому сожалению я не могу выложить полный код, но возможно у кого-то есть объяснение аномалии? Никаких переменных на полях класса нет, чертовщина происходит на базе Angular 7.

Comment: (метод тыка): А если `String( value ).split(...` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME это первым делом попробовал что бы новый экземпляр создать. Пересобирать проект пробовал не помогло.

Comment: `'1 2345'.charCodeAt(1)`?

Comment: Может быть это другой пробел (например неразрывный).

Comment: @Yaant отдает 160

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132348/what-does-char-160-mean-in-my-source-code